# invalid initialization of reference of type ‘short int (&)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an array to a function but I'm getting this weird error

```
const int size = 2;
void foo(short (&a)[size]){
  cout << a;
}
void testSequence(short a[size]){
  foo(a);
}
```

error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘short int (&)[4]’ from expression of type ‘short int*’

Comment: The error message is very clear. You are passing a `short` to the function when it expects a reference to an array of 4 `short`s.

Comment: roters is an array, its getting passed as an argument and when I try to pass it to the next function it can't

Comment: It's time to post a [mcve], then.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. `roters` in `testSequence` is a pointer, not an array, despite being declared with `[]`.

Comment: Helpful reading; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a *function parameter* like this

```
short a[size]
```

you are declaring a pointer, not an array:

> [dcl.fct] After determining
>   the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”.

`foo(short (&a)[size])` requires a reference to an array of size `size`. A pointer cannot be converted to one.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
void testSequence(short a[size]);
```

is the same as

```
void testSequence(short a[]);
```

which is the same as

```
void testSequence(short* a);
```

Hence, the call

```
foo(a);
```

from the function is not valid.

In order to be able to use

```
foo(a);
```

you'll have to use:

```
void testSequence(short (&a)[size]){
  foo(a);
}
```

---

The line

```
cout << a;
```

in `foo` is not right either. There is no overload of the `<<` operator that allows writing a reference to an array of `int`s to `cout`. You can use:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
   std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}
```